# How to redirect the output of time command to a log file?

Tags: bash, shell, time

I have a few servers which are acting strangely, so in order to find the problem, I wrote some bash script which is supposed to run some basic tests and output them to a log file.

The script looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
PENDERLIST="/root/pender.list"
PING="/bin/ping"
ETHTOOL="/sbin/ethtool"
FILE="/root/14mfile"
function writelog
{
        echo "$(/bin/date +%F) $(/bin/date +%R): $*"
}
for SRV in $(cat $PENDERLIST); do
writelog "################### Begin $SRV ########################"
echo "### PING ###"
$PING $SRV -c 2
ssh root@$SRV "yum install lshw -y"
echo "### Uname -a ###"
ssh root@$SRV "uname -a"
echo "### Release ###"
ssh root@$SRV "/bin/cat /etc/*release*"
LSHW=$(ssh root@$SRV "lshw -C network |grep eth | awk 'NR==1' ")
NIC=$(echo $LSHW |  awk -F: '{print $2}')
echo "### IFCONFIG ###"
ssh root@$SRV "ifconfig"
echo "### ETHTOOL ###"
ssh root@$SRV "ethtool $NIC"
echo "### FILE TRANSFER ###"
time scp $FILE root@$SRV
writelog "############## End of report for $SRV #################"
done
```

I'm running it like so:

```
./check_server.sh > log.txt
```

All the output is written to the log successfully apart from the time command there.
I've tried changing the command to:

```
(time scp $FILE root@$SRV) 2> log.txt
{ time ls; } 2> out.txt
```

But both print the output of `time` to the screen rather than to the log.txt file.
How can I redirect time's output to the log?

Edit #1:

While checking the log, at the line where the output of time should be, I see this:

```
### FILE TRANSFER ### 
2014-11-23 02:31: ############## End of report for pender4.company.com #################
2014-11-23 02:31: ################### Begin pender5.company.com ########################
```

Comment: 2 is for redirecting standard error. try appending to log file (time scp $FILE root@$SRV) >> log.txt

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, tried it but to no avail.

Comment: did you checked your log.txt? As whatever you echo or write to standard output, you are redirceting to log.txt?

Comment: You can send all output to the logs with `./script >>logfile 2>&1` which redirects both `stdout/stderr` to `logfile`. However, I generally prefer sending only the info in the script I want to the log. In the script, setup `logfile=/path/to/logfile.log`, then at the end of each statement you care about logging, pipe to `tee` to get the info to both the `log` and `stdout` e.g. `somecommand | tee -a $logfile` (`-a` for append). You can even keep your logs compressed and uncompress while the script runs, write to them, compress at end. Whatever you taste.

Comment: I'll try it now and let you know, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

time command is shell keyword... when your run `time` command in terminal it's not `/usr/bin/time` so the options like `-a` and  `-o` will not work with `time` command. However `man time` will still display man page of `/usr/bin/time` .You have to use `/usr/bin/time -o logfile command`  to redirect the time's output to file `logfile` or you can use the following command which is similar to shell's keyword `time`:

`/usr/bin/time -o time_log -f "%E real,%U user,%S sys" [command] [args]` to redirect the time's output to file `time_log`